# How to wait until the async request is complete

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've an ajax registration form. The user may type in the desired username in the input field and then immediately hit the register button, while the ajax request to check if the username is available or not wasn't completed. For this case I want the actions of the register button to start executing only if the ajax request to check username is complete, otherwise wait for it to complete and then proceed. How to do this?

I want the username validation function to remain asynchronous because it executes every time the user does a key-up on the input field.

One way is to enter into a setTimeout() loop when the register button is clicked, and to stay in it until the flag is good. Another way is to call a synch username check request if the asynch request isn't complete. Is there a better method?

It'll be nice if you give answer without using jQuery.

Comment: This is something you can do pretty easily in jQuery. Is this something you'd be ok with? You would use the success callback for this.

Comment: Instead of jQuery I'll prefer a conceptual explanation of what to do. I don't know jQuery.

Comment: Erm... so you need the register button to be disabled until the username is validated, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use setTimeout for this.

Simply use the callback capabilities of [jquery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) : execute your "after" code in the `success` callback or the new `done` helper :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html"
}).done(function() { 
  // do things after the answer has been received
});
```

**EDIT :**

Without jquery, and without immediate triggering :

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var requestDoneAndOK = false;
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
                requestDoneAndOK = true;
        }               
    }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
```

And when the "register" button is clicked, you just have to check `requestDoneAndOK` and if it's true call your other function.

**EDIT 2 :**

Code is executed as soon as 2 conditions are realized : answer received and register button clicked.

```
var registerClicked = false;
var ajaxAnswerReceived = false;
function check() {
    if (registerClicked && ajaxAnswerReceived) {
         // do the thing !
    }
}
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
var requestDoneAndOK = false;
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
              ajaxAnswerReceived = true;
                check();
        }               
    }
};
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
document.getElementById('registerButton').onclick = function(){
     registerClicked = true;
     check();
};
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but user1444680  stated that he preferred a solution without jQuery.

Comment: I don't know jQuery but what I can understand is that my functions will be triggered automatically when the ajax request is complete. I don't want that. I want them to trigger when the "register" button is clicked. And after it's clicked, it's checked whether the ajax request which was made before the click is complete or not.

Comment: @koenp OOps. I've read too fast the last line of the question... I understood OP specifically *wanted* jquery...

Comment: @user1444680 Edited, without jquery and without immediate callback execution.

Comment: I know till here. But what if requestDoneAndOk is false? I want the javascript to wait until it becomes true. That's what my question is. How to wait for it to become true?

Comment: You want your code to execute as soon as 2 conditions are realized : answer received and user clicked ?

Comment: You don't have to wait, that is the beauty of the async callbacks. Just prevent the form from being submitted until the validation is complete.

Comment: @dystroy Yes and I also don't want that the user has to click the register button again.

Comment: What if I prevent the form from being submitted? The user will have to click again. I don't want that.

Comment: @user1444680 OK. So I think the new edit is what you're looking for.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks. To check after completing the ajax query if the register button was clicked, nice idea. But the registration validation may generate an error so the form can't submit - In that case I'll reset the registerClicked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this without jQuery you'll need to use the default JavaScript call mechanism using onreadystatechange. Remember that jQuery is just a wrapper around the default mechanisms. I do recommend that you use jQuery or something else just to prevent a whole slew of cross browser issues and http state change logic.

Read all about the native stuff here: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Answer (score 0):

You need to use callbacks and store validation flag booleans that you then need to check before the user submits the registration page. This is a jquery implementation, but its not difficult to turn it into regular js. The method is defined here:

```
var goodUsername = false;

// keyup handler, pseudo code 
$('#username').keyup(function(event) { 
    // perform the username validation with an ajax call:
    $.ajax({
        url: "validateUsername.php"
    }).done(function(data) {
        // set the goodUsername if its good or not
        if (data.usernameIsGood)
            goodUserName = true;
    });
});

// submit the registration form only if the username has been checked and is good
$('#registrationFormButton').click(function(event){
     if (goodUsername)
         return true; // allows the browser to submit the form
     else
         return false;
});
```

Comment: "if (goodUsername)
         return true; // allows the browser to submit the form
     else
         return false;"   
I don't want to return false, I want it to wait until it's true.

Comment: That particular function allows the form to be submitted. When it returns true, the click event is passed to the browser and the browser submits the form. If you return false there (because the user name is bad) then the browser never sees the click event and doesn't submit the form. Thus async waiting.

Comment: Oh, I don't know jQuery that's why I misunderstood.